# How to start the accessibilities settings menu

Tags: android, service, accessibility

I currently have a fully functioning accessibility service that functions and all, I was wondering how to launch the accessibilities settings menu in order to enable the service for the first run of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));`